# Not able to convert RGB image to GrayScale

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am having numpy 4d array of colored images shaped (1000,3,100,100) (float values)  train_img, which I want to convert it to shaped (20000,1,100,100) of grayscale images but I am getting below error. How do I rectify it?

For the below code I am getting error mentioned below.

```
 train_img[0]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[0], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

 for i in range(train_img.shape[0]):
    train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-ff9e3a020a5c>", line 2, in <module>
    train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11010: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor



OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11016
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgcodecs\src\utils.cpp, line 622
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010

for i in range(train_img.shape[0]):
    
    train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-e993ce67611f>", line 3, in <module>
    train_img[i]= cv2.cvtColor(train_img[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11010: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor



OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11010
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 11016
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file
```

Comment: Shouldn't the shape of image be `(100,100,3)` and not `(3,100,100)` when feeding to opencv?

Comment: @SuryaTej Tried both shapes, getting the same error.

Comment: What is the output of train_img.shape? It should look something like (1000, 100, 100, 3). Quite likely number of channels is being passed as 100.

Comment: You can use `img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` instead of BGR->RGB->Gray conversion. Also check the number of channels in the image like `if image.ndim == 2: channels = 1 #single (grayscale)  if image.ndim == 3: channels = image.shape[-1]` For training the convention is [Batch_size, channels, height, width]

Comment: How does the maths work out here `(1000,3,100,100)` to `(20000,1,100,100) ` by shape conversion? You can get 4d array of grayscales `(1000,1,100,100)`.